# reverse geolocation with open graph action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, reverse-geocoding

I am developing an application which has an associated lat,long with the action in open graph. Presently, the api only allows for a place, so I have created my own location object which can be a property of the action.

The problem I perceive here is that this will not form part of the action in a very Facebook way.

I do not want to use Facebook places, nor do I want to have the use create a place when performing an action.

I don't need a lot of granularity, instead, just need "near $locality", such as a village name or national park if no residential addresses exist. This seems to be what happens with the Facebook messages.

Do we know a way of getting low fidelity data from Facebook or other (free) source which allow for locality information to be attached to an action?

Cheers